# DirectShow Source Filter

Tags: c++, com, filter, directshow, windows-mobile-6.5

I have created directShow Source filter, it tested on Win32, and works fine.
But when I port them on windows Mobile 6.5.3

After calling CoCreateInstance(MyfilterGUID),
I have such:

```
hr  0x8007007e {The specified module could not be found. }  HRESULT
```

Why this happens? I suppose this because something wrong with my DirectShow dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this issue, that's happens because, my DLL has dependencies from MS dll msvcr80d.dll. To fix this needed in Visual Studio **Project Properties -> General -> Use of MFC** set **Use MFC in a Static Library**. And all works...